# PHImageManager getting photo incorrectly because of edit from photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, phasset

I have a strange issue about getting UIImages with PHImageManager.

Everything works fine with when the requested UIImage is not edited from photos app of iPhone;

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:[assets objectAtIndex:0] targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:requestOptions resultHandler:^void(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info)
         {
             DebugLog(@"%ld", assets.count);
             @autoreleasepool
             {
                 if (image)
                 {
                     // Write image to system
                     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                     NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld_%@.jpg", (long)assets.count, [NSDate date]];
                     NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
                     [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

                 }
         }];
```

But in case that if a user edited the photo from iPhone's self photo editor (i.e. s/he cropped the picture) the PHImageManager fails to retrieve that photo.

**Without editing**, the dictionary provided in the resultHandler is normal which is called "info":

```
{
PHImageFileOrientationKey = 0;
PHImageFileSandboxExtensionTokenKey = "5565e83d376d8c4e018b8ea41401e58e5aabbc18;00000000;00000000;000000000000001a;com.apple.app-sandbox.read;00000001;01000003;000000000039a762;/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/113APPLE/IMG_3433.PNG";
PHImageFileURLKey = "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/113APPLE/IMG_3433.PNG";
PHImageFileUTIKey = "public.png";
PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 9999;
PHImageResultIsDegradedKey = 0;
PHImageResultIsInCloudKey = 0;
PHImageResultIsPlaceholderKey = 0;
PHImageResultOptimizedForSharing = 0;
PHImageResultRequestIDKey = 55;
PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 9999;
```

}

But **after editing** from photo application the dictionary becomes:

```
{
PHImageFileOrientationKey = 0;
PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 4031;
PHImageResultIsDegradedKey = 1;
PHImageResultRequestIDKey = 56;
PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 9998;
```

}

Does anyone faced with this issue before?

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I find out what happens there.

In PHImageRequestOptions there is an option to choose the unadjusted version of the photo by adding;

```
requestOptions.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionUnadjusted;
```

With this, I successfully get the Image (however in unadjusted format).

Anyone could find further solution without taking the image adjusted, please comment me.

Cheers.

Comment: Hello, Onur, did you find a solution for this? I'm facing a similar issue with the sizes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302772/ios-phcachingimagemanager-requestimage-wrong-image-size-after-rotating-the-image

Comment: @NunoGonçalves no actually, I used the unadjusted version of the photo. It had been over 3 years that I asked and not bumped any solution for this though :(

Answer (score 0):

I am too late to help you now, but maybe someone else will have the same issue in the future.

Instead of `PHImageRequestOptionsVersionUnadjusted` use `PHImage​Request​Options​Delivery​Mode​High​Quality​Format`.

Or in **Swift** use,

```
requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.highQualityFormat
```

If you check the documentation for `highQualityFormat`:

> Photos provides only the highest-quality image available, regardless
>   of how much time it takes to load. If the isSynchronous property is
>   true or if using the requestImageData(for:options:resultHandler:)
>   method, this behavior is the default and only option (that is,
>   specifying other delivery mode options has no effect).

Comment: Note : PHImageRequestOptionsVersion and PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode are different enums.

Comment: I tried this but doesn't help in my case. It's a similar question: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302772/ios-phcachingimagemanager-requestimage-wrong-image-size-after-rotating-the-image)

Comment: I guess JPetric's solution is not the answer you are looking for @NunoGonçalves