# iOS PHCachingImageManager requestImage wrong image size after rotating the image on the photos app

Tags: ios

I'm fetching images using the `requestImage` of the `PHCachingImageManager`.

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.version = .current

PHCachingImageManager().requestImage(
    for: asset,
    targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, // resizeMode will be ignored
    contentMode: .default, // defaults to aspectFit
    options: options,
    resultHandler: { image, _ in
        image.size // => <output image size>
    }
)
```

This works pretty well for most cases, but I found an issue that I'd like to correct.

I want the original image, hence the `PHImageManagerMaximumSize` property. 
The resulting image size for an unrotated image is 4032x3024 or 3024x4032 depending on the orientation.

As soon as I rotate the image in the Photos app of the phone, I get a size of 1500x1124.

**Original**

*(lldb) po asset:*

> E8710CF9-BA53-49FA-8535-D2B41EFA7AF2/L0/001
>   mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (4032x3024), creationDate=2019-05-24
>   06:42:17 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0 
>   burst=579849A0-156F-4F53-B368-BE09B8502DE0/2

*(lldb) po image*

> ▿ Optional
>     - some : , {4032, 3024}

**Rotated:**

*(lldb) po asset:*

> 0x10760df20> E8710CF9-BA53-49FA-8535-D2B41EFA7AF2/L0/001
>   mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (4032x3024), creationDate=2019-05-25
>   06:18:13 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0

(lldb) po image

> ▿ Optional
>     - some : , {1500, 1124}

The asset's information size seems ok, only the resulting uiimage size is not.

I tried playing with the options but none seem to matter. I tried uploading the image via airdrop and the size seems ok, so I must be doing something wrong.

Are there any ideas out there that might help?

Comment: Have you tried setting the deliveryMode of PHImageRequestOptions to PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat?

Comment: Gosh. It has been so long since I worked on this. I ended up ignoring it and making sure I upload first and rotate first. Since it’s not a production app. But would be useful to try Again indeed.